# How to multiply span inner by id using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a span which shows a currency.
This is my span:

```
<span id="v3_40"></span>
```

It will only show the currency when it's being loaded through a browser and it needs the script bellow to show the result:

```
<script src="//service.arzlive.com/p.js"></script>
```

It shows a currency number like this: 38,355

How can i extract this number out from this span and multiply it by another number and show it as the result in another span?
I need a code to get the numeric value out from the span

Comment: Take a look at the javascript function: innerHTML() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` to get and set your `span` values.

```js
document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = document.getElementById('v3_40').innerHTML * 12;
```

```html
<span id="v3_40">38.355</span>
* 12 = 
<span id="new"></span>
```

EDIT:

After seeing the comments to this answer, here's a more detailed approach;

```
var originalPrice = document.getElementById('v3_40').innerHTML;
var price = originalPrice.replace(/\,/g,'');
var newPrice = parseFloat(price,20) * 12;
newPrice = newPrice.toLocaleString();

document.getElementById('new').textContent = newPrice;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Probably better to use textContent instead of innerHTML and parse it before multiplying: `parseInt(document.getElementById('new'), 10)` or `parseFloat(document.getElementById('new'), 10)`.

Comment: thanks so much guys i did it ..
but there is a problem with comma in the middle
@FissureKing the number is 38,555 but it only shows 38 when i use parseFloat

Comment: Hmm, yeah my bad.  You could use a replace function to reject any non-numeric or decimal characters, but this could possibly raise some locale issues: `parseFloat(document.getElementById('new').textContent.replace(/[^0-9\.]*/g, ''), 10)`

Comment: @FissureKing, I added your suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Cool!  Instead of your manual formatting, you should just set the value to `newPrice.toLocaleString()`.

Comment: thanks very much guys it worked fine and my problem is solved! thanks