# Multiply span inner text by input text value. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make it so for each line the user enters a value for, this value is then multiplied by its corresponding dollar amount and finally added to input text ESTIMATE_TTL

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <small><strong>ESTIMATE - TOTAL</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ESTIMATE_TTL" name="ESTIMATE_TTL" placeholder="$0.00" type="text" input="" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4">
    <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;REFRESH</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I multiply the span inner text of a span id with its corresponding text input then increment div estimate id by this calculated amount.

Here's a working link for you to visualize it

[Online Example here](http://nexlevel.org/autosave8/)

Example

```
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_WTRESRVD" name="EA_WTRESRVD" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_WTRESRVD" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_WTRESRVD" class="input-group-addon">$122.67</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HRS</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_WTRESRV" name="EA_WTRESRV" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_WTRESRV" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_WTRESRV" class="input-group-addon">$184.00</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>ASBESTOS TEST FEE</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_FEEASBT" name="EA_FEEASBT" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_FEEASBT" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_FEEASBT" class="input-group-addon">$300.00</span> </div>
</div>
```

The REFRESH button can go away if I can managed to incorporate this on my keyup event but if not it's fine as well.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service...the objective is to help you fix **your code**. Finding examples and tutorials about  calculators on the web is not hard

Comment: I have tried using this post to understand it but I did not succeed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812141/how-to-multiply-span-inner-by-id-using-javascript

Comment: Finding a regex that parses dollar to float...

Comment: Use `replace()`. Not hard to search for that part by itself. Still show what you tried

Comment: Thanks for allowing me to lose me all these reputation points charlietfl. Very informative.

Comment: Do you come here for help or reputation points? If it's for help there are basic guidelines as outlined in [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small demo to help you out. Total will get updated on every `focusout` of the `input` selector.

```js
$(".form-control-sm").on('focusout', function() {
  var price = $(this).parent().find(".input-group-addon").text();
  price = parseFloat(price.replace('EA$', ''));
  var enteredVal = $(this).val() != '' ? $(this).val() : 0;
  var total = price * enteredVal;
  $(".totalPrice").text(parseFloat($(".totalPrice").text()) + total);
});
```

```css
.totalPrice {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_WTRESRVD" name="EA_WTRESRVD" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_WTRESRVD" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_WTRESRVD" class="input-group-addon">$122.67</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>EMERGENCY SERVICE CALL AFTER HRS</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_WTRESRV" name="EA_WTRESRV" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_WTRESRV" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_WTRESRV" class="input-group-addon">$184.00</span> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"> <small><strong>ASBESTOS TEST FEE</strong></small>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm my-1"><span class="input-group-addon">EA</span>
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="EA_FEEASBT" name="EA_FEEASBT" placeholder="0" type="text" input pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" value="" maxlength="4"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i id="STS_FEEASBT" class="fa fa-stop fa-lg"></i></span>    <span id="PRC_FEEASBT" class="input-group-addon">$300.00</span> </div>
</div>


Total: <span class='totalPrice'>0</span>
```

Comment: Cool. I'll give it a try when I get home.